# cannot add mbedtls to project

Tags: c, cmake, mbedtls

Trying to add mbedtls to my project, I use apt-get install to install libmbedtls-dev
are these imports incorrect? for Ubuntu 16.04.works fine on 18.04

```
file (GLOB C_FILES *.c)
file (GLOB H_FILES "../../../include/thrift/ssl/*.h")
add_library (thrift_tcp_ssl ${THRIFT_LIB_TYPE} ${C_FILES} ${H_FILES})
target_link_libraries (thrift_tcp_ssl PRIVATE thrift -lmbedtls -lmbedx509 -lmbedcrypto)
target_include_directories (thrift_tcp_ssl PRIVATE ../../../include)
install (TARGETS thrift_tcp_ssl LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

get this error for unbuntu 16

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmbedtls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In two steps:

1. `sudo apt-cache search mbedtls`,
   which shows what possiblities you have on your system.
2. `sudo apt install libmbedtls-dev libmbedtls10`,
   change to versions you have on your system.